# How I pass parameters to the header in Rest application?

Tags: delphi

In Delphi Rest application how I pass header parameters ? I tried `params` property in `RESTRequest1` component but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values in <> brackets are placeholders:

```
RestRequest1.AddParameter(<param name>, <param value>, pkHTTPHEADER, [<perhaps poDoNotEncode>]);
```